# How do you Import a list item from a .cmp file using powershell?

Tags: 2007, powershell, content-deployment, events, document-migration

I have implemented the code located at [this link](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/10/copy-sharepoint-lists-and-document.html) to export and import a list to a cmp file using powershell and the SPDeployment functions. While trying to better understand this code I came to the realization that I can use the same code (with a few adjustments) to export a single item by giving it the item unique ID, the type file (or list item), and the folder server relative url. My question is how would I modify the import-list to import this item in a specific folder/list. I read [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2007/08/30/deep-dive-into-the-sharepoint-content-deployment-and-migration-api-part-3.aspx) article but it is in another language. I'm not sure how to convert it to powershell. I also, wasn't sure if the register-objectevent was the proper method but I also didn't want to do an "inline" function.

At first I thought I simply needed to give it a import object but there is no API to do so. I suspect I need to add this line:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $import -EventName started `
-SourceIdentifier $import.started -Action { importStart   }
```

And the following function:

```
Function importStart([object]$sender, [object]$args)#[Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPDeploymentEventArgs]$args) 
{
   write-host "successfully entered started2"
   $web = #get list web somehow
   $list = #get list somehow

   $rootObjects = $args.RootObjects; 
   foreach ($io in $rootObjects) 
   { 
      if ($io.Type -eq [Microsoft.Sharepoint.Deployment.SPDeploymentObjectType]::File -or 
        $io.Type -eq [Microsoft.Sharepoint.Deployment.SPDeploymentObjectType]::ListItem)               
      {                                                             
         $io.TargetParentUrl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;    
      }                                                             
      if ($io.Type -eq [Microsoft.Sharepoint.Deployment.SPDeploymentObjectType]::List)                   
      {                                                             
         $io.TargetParentUrl = $web.Url;                              
      }
   }
   $web.dispose();
}
```

But there are no event arguments passed to the -action command block or the function. Am I missing something here?
Please help!